# Verilog For loop with no condition gives error: expecting operand

Tags: for-loop, verilog

I am using Verilog (not SystemVerilog) and trying to use a `for` loop with no condition in the middle.

It says "expecting operand".

```
for(x=5;;x++ ) begin
            led[x] <= 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verilog `for` loop requires a middle condition. Verilog does not have the `++` operator either.